# Oracle - transaction scope of the WITH clause

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, transactions

Consider following Java/JUnit integration test scenario.

There's a *current time* DB table where a current processing day is stored and the integration test is updating it to mock the test time (I would rather not discuss whether that's a good approach or not). The test runs within a transaction and everything is rollbacked at the end.

Now, after the time is mocked, a stored procedure that queries the *current time* table is executed and does some processing based on that.

The time is queried multiple times there, but particularly inside the **WITH** clause, the updated mocked time is not read, but rather an old one that was already there before (e.g. the state before the test begun).

It seems like the transaction boundaries are not respected in this case. My theory is that it has something to do with the fact that Oracle constructs temporary table for the **WITH** queries, but I've found no evidence for that whatsoever.

The actual SQLs with the comments explaining what's going on:

```
-- mocking of the test time
-- updates the CURRENT_RUN_DATE to the test time, the previous value was 2016-06-14 08:30:51
UPDATE CURRENT_RUN_DATE SET RUN_DATE = '2014-10-06 07:05:00';

-- SQL of the actual Stored Procedure

WITH SOME_TEMPORARY_VIEW
AS (
  SELECT
    *  
  FROM MY_DATA_TABLE d
  WHERE
-- function F_PREVIOUS_RUN_DATE just select the RUN_DATE from CURRENT_RUN_DATE,
-- yet the old value is read
    d.RUN_DATE = (SELECT F_PREVIOUS_RUN_DATE  FROM DUAL)
)

SELECT
-- here goes some more sql, not important
-- however, if the F_PREVIOUS_RUN_DATE is called here, 
-- it reads the correct RUN_DATE, e.g. the one that was set in the first step
 *
FROM SOME_TEMPORARY_VIEW mv;
```

The Oracle version used: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0

### Update

Based on the answers/comments I am adding more details.
In the stored procedure, two WITH clauses are actually used.
The dependency is `ACTUAL_SELECT_STATEMENT -> ANOTHER_VIEW -> SOME_TEMPORARY_VIEW`

The actual SQL:

```
-- mocking of the test time
-- updates the CURRENT_RUN_DATE to the test time, the previous value was 2016-06-14 08:30:51
UPDATE CURRENT_RUN_DATE SET RUN_DATE = '2014-10-06 07:05:00';

-- here begins the problematic SQL
WITH SOME_TEMPORARY_VIEW
AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT F_PREVIOUS_RUN_DATE FROM DUAL) as PREVIOUS_RUN_DATE_DEBUG
  FROM MY_DATA_TABLE stic
  WHERE
    -- F_PREVIOUS_RUN_DATE select the PREVIOUS_RUN_DATE from CURRENT_RUN_DATE
    -- the old incosistent value is read here
    stic.RUN_DATE = (SELECT F_PREVIOUS_RUN_DATE FROM DUAL)
),
    ANOTHER_VIEW
  AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT
      -- selects from the first view, does some calculations
        *
      FROM SOME_TEMPORARY_VIEW tv)
SELECT
mv.*,
-- F_PREVIOUS_RUN_DATE reads correct value here
(SELECT F_PREVIOUS_RUN_DATE FROM DUAL) AS PREVIOUS_RUN_DATE_DEBUG2
FROM ANOTHER_VIEW mv;
```

Here's the screenshot proving that inconsistent data is read (see the DEBUG columns):
[image: query_result]

Anyway, thanks @ibre5041 for the info about the hints.

And here goes the interesting story.

After I applied the `INLINE` hint, the query **did work** as expected. It looks like the problem is somehow related to WITH and materialization into  temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

With a plain SQL statement, Oracle picks a time (or more precisely a System Change Number or SCN) and the data used is consistent as of that point in time.

When you use a stored function (irrespective of WHEN) in a query, that gets thrown out of the window. The Optimizer may choose to execute the function one or multiple times, and any queries executed within that function operate as of a independent point in time/SCN.

You may be able to use

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

to make Oracle use the same SCN for the duration of the whole transaction. 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10743/consist.htm#i17846

Comment: Thanks, tried to set isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE`, but still the same result. Anyway, you might want to take a look at the updated post, I would say the whole thing looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

If it works like you describe then it is a bug. The `WITH` clause can be either inlined or materialized (see `INLINE` and `MATERIALIZE` hints). Use these hints and check how execution plan changes. In both cases the query must access read consistent data. And also must return same results.

This could happen if you called pl/sql functions, these also call sql. Then these functions could see phantom (newly created data) - as they run in a different SCN context. As @Gary described.

Comment: Indeed, with the `INLINE`, the query started to behave correctly, I've added more details into the post.

Comment: If hints change the results, then definitelly you face Oracle bug. I recall I saw something similar some time ago. Either blindly appy latest PSU or contact Oracle support.

Comment: See anwser from @alex http://stackoverflow.com/a/35773050/836215